# How to add subView to anotherSubView with center alignment in iOS swift.

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm using lottie library for animation. I loaded lottieFile as subView to anotherSubView but it's not aligned in center. I tried using center attributes as below:

```
@IBOutlet weak var viewOn: UIView!

let animationView = LOTAnimationView(name: "restless_gift_ii") {
animationView.loopAnimation = true
animationView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
animationView.animationSpeed = 1
animationView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
animationView.frame.size = viewOn.frame.size
animationView.center.x = viewOn.center.x
animationView.center.y = viewOn.center.y
viewOn.addSubview(animationView) }
```

[image: Result not aligned]

Answer (score 10):

You can use auto layout programmatically to center align your animation view into it’s super view.

Here, I have added two ways to add `animationView` center align and also added comments for understanding.

```
if let animationView = LOTAnimationView(name: "4_bar_loop") {

        animationView.loopAnimation = true
        animationView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        animationView.animationSpeed = 1
        animationView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

        self.viewOn.addSubview(animationView)

        animationView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // Apply these constrains if you want animation size should be same as super view.
        self.viewOn.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: animationView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.viewOn, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 1))
        self.viewOn.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: animationView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.viewOn, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 1))
        self.viewOn.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: animationView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.viewOn, attribute:.top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 1))
        self.viewOn.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: animationView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.viewOn, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 1))


        // Apply these constraint if you want animationView with fixed height and width and center of super view.
//            self.viewOn.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: animationView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.viewOn, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 1))
//            self.viewOn.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: animationView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.viewOn, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 1))
//            animationView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: animationView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 100))
//            animationView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: animationView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 100))
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

[image]

you can do it like code below programmatically i hope this help you

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let firstView:UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        return view
    }()

    let secondView:UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews(){

        view.addSubview(firstView)
        firstView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        firstView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        firstView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        firstView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

        // second view
        firstView.addSubview(secondView)
        secondView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstView.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        secondView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstView.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        secondView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        secondView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@IBOutlet weak var viewOn: UIView!

let animationView = LOTAnimationView(name: "restless_gift_ii")
{
    animationView.loopAnimation = true
    animationView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    animationView.animationSpeed = 1
    animationView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    animationView.frame = viewOn.frame
    viewOn.addSubview(animationView)
}
```

You can try it, hope it's OK

Answer (score 0):

I was having several problems with the alignment and scaling of my Lottie animations. They would show up centered on emulator but not on devices. After debugging for hours, I found out the layout issues were happening because I was setting up the animations on the `viewDidLoad()`. When I moved the code to `viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)` everything worked like a charm. I hope this may help someone else.